# anchor tag first click is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have links inside bootstrap dropdown which I dynamically add from script.

```
"<ul><li><a class='view' href='" + Url + Name + "/" + Id + "' target='_blank' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title=' + Name + ' + "'>" + Name + "</a></li></ul>"
```

**Edit: Code in browser**
`<a class="view" href="https://example/test/a314784-dcdc-4712-acf1-c29ed271e87b" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="test">test</a>`

When I click this link first time, it is not working. Second click is working.
Only 1st click after page load is not working in chrome.

It is working fine in safari, firefox, edge and IE browsers.

I shouldn't change this to button and onclick event. How to fix this issue in chrome browser ?

Comment: We'll need a proper [mcve], since obviously what's in the question is just a link. Links work. Also, when asking about a client-side issue, show only the client-side code (what the browser sees), not your server-side code generating it.

Comment: `data-toggle='tooltip'` suggests their might be other functionality bound to this ... and maybe that is interfering.

Comment: @CBroe I have tried by removing data-toggle='tooltip',  but not worked.